# How can I fix disable telemetry in flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Who knows that how I can fix it?

Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.
Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:
flutter --disable-telemetry.
If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
and then no further information will be sent.
This data is collected in accordance with the
Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).
Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.
Exited (1)

I can`t run my project. when run it, this error appears in debug consule: Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options.

The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.
Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:
flutter --disable-telemetry.
If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
and then no further information will be sent.
This data is collected in accordance with the
Google Privacy Policy (https://policies.google.com/privacy).
Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.
Exited (1)

p.s: my dart sdk is 3.0.2 and my flutter sdk is 3.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your `.vscode/launch.json`, `.vscode/settings.json` or your VS Code User Settings to see if you have added "no-sound-null-safety" to the `args` passed to the application or a setting like `flutterRunAdditionalArgs`.

If you have, it's likely you should've put `--` in front of it, making it `"--no-sound-null-safety"`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I tried everything, but the final solution was:

```
flutter downgrade
```